# Java ArrayList Syntax Error

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm getting an error when declaring this ArrayList as an instance variable in Java.

```
private ArrayList<char> correctGuesses = new ArrayList<char>();
```

The error:

```
Syntax error on token char, Dimension expected after this token
```

Can I not make ArrayLists with type char?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't use a primitive type, rather you use its Wrapper class.. So instead of `char` you would have `Character`

```
ArrayList<Character> correctGuesses = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use primitives as generic parameters. Instead, you use the wrapped version.
Try this:

```
private ArrayList<Character> correctGuesses = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

You can still add `char` types to it though, because java auto-boxes them. ie

```
correctGuesses.add((char)63);
```

would be a legal statement.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `ArrayList` using `Character`:

```
private ArrayList<Character> correctGuesses = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Generics don't work with simple types, they require Objects.